# Getting a number when it has certain prefix from a block of text in PHP

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have a big paragraph and at a random point in it a string like this occurs which I'd like to extract:

```
PID: 45678437
```

There is a space before 'PID' and after the number, the number can be 6-10 characters in length.

I actually only need the number but would like to check it is preceded with PID: as there may be other large numbers in the paragraph.

:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/ PID: (\d{6,10})/
```

This will match a space followed by `PID:` followed by a space followed by 6-10 digits and *capture* the digits.

I would encourage you to learn [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info). They are a powerful tool.

Comment: This is a really useful link too: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$pattern = '~(?<=\sPID:\s)[0-9]{6,10}(?=\s)~';
preg_match($pattern, $text, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

The idea is to use lookaround to only checks characters before and after the number without matching them.

Comment: Why do you *need* the lookaround?

Comment: Note `\s` will match also other *whitespace*.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $string = "PID: 4567895";
    preg_match("/PID:\s(\d{6,10})/", $string, $result);
    $value = $result[0];
    echo "The value is: {$value}";
?>
```

Comment: Note `\s` will match also other *whitespace*.